How to verify whether calls are actually made in Cypress
I'm trying in cypress tests to check that the API call is only made once.
Then I try to keep making changes, and I wanted to verify that the calls aren't actually being made.
  it("update statement from the map is edited and sent only once", () => {
    cy.intercept("POST", mapsPath, { fixture: "initDefaultMap.json" }).as("saveMap");
    cy.intercept("POST", lrsPath, { fixture: "statementOpened.json" }).as("statementUpdatedMap");

    cy.get('[data-cy="canvas"]').click();
    cy.get("zt-color-picker[icon='bg-color']").shadow().find("zt-button").shadow().find(".zt-button").click();
    cy.get("zt-color-picker[icon='bg-color']")
      .shadow()
      .find("#color-picker-submenu > ul > li.color-boxes[data-color='#99FFCC']")
      .click();

    cy.wait("@statementUpdatedMap").then((evt) => expect(extractVerb(evt)).to.be.equal("updated"));
    cy.wait("@saveMap");
    cy.intercept("POST", lrsPath, cy.spy());
    cy.get('[data-cy="edit-title"]').click();
    cy.get("body [data-cy='input-title'] input").clear().type("mappa bella");
    cy.get('[data-cy="canvas"]').click();
    cy.wait(1000).then(() => expect(cy.spy()).not.to.be.called);
    cy.get("zt-color-picker[icon='bg-color']").shadow().find("zt-button").shadow().find(".zt-button").click();
    cy.get("zt-color-picker[icon='bg-color']")
      .shadow()
      .find("#color-picker-submenu > ul > li.color-boxes[data-color='#5533FF']")
      .click();
    cy.wait(1000).then(() => expect(cy.spy()).not.to.be.called);
  });

I tried using cy.spy(), but it didn't work

It is unfortunate that the cy.intercept() does not allow direct verification that calls occur a fixed number of times.
If I simulate your code by sending the POST via cy.window(), I can see the test fails when I wait for a second call that never occurs:
const lrsPath = 'endpoint'   // for example

cy.intercept("POST", lrsPath, { fixture: "statementOpened.json" })
  .as("statementUpdatedMap");

// trigger the post (simulated)
cy.window().then(win => {
  win.fetch(lrsPath, { method: "POST" })
})

cy.wait("@statementUpdatedMap")  // wait for one call

cy.wait("@statementUpdatedMap")  // wait for another call

then the test fails:


Turning a failing test into a passing test
I can turn that into a passing test by verifying that a failure message was raised.

using cy.on('fail') to catch the error
verifying the error message to make sure it's the right error
using Mocha done() function to make sure the error was thrown (Mocha done() is a parameter to the it() function)

I use the following custom command
Cypress.Commands.add('verifyFailed', (expectedMessage, done) => {
  function handleFail(error) {
    const actual = error.message
    const passed = actual.includes(expectedMessage)
    const log = passed ? 'Correct error thrown' :
      `"${expected}", actual: "${actual}"`
    assert(passed, log)
    cy.off('fail', handleFail)
    done()
  }
  cy.on('fail', handleFail)
})

Then I use it in the test at the point it fails, in this case before the second cy.wait('@statementUpdatedMap').
it('turn a failing test into a passing test with Mocha done()', (done) => {

  const lrsPath = 'endpoint'   // for example

  cy.intercept("POST", lrsPath, { fixture: "statementOpened.json" })
    .as("statementUpdatedMap");

  // trigger the post (simulated)
  cy.window().then(win => {
    win.fetch(lrsPath, { method: "POST" })
  })

  cy.wait("@statementUpdatedMap")  // wait for one call

  cy.verifyFailed('No request ever occurred', done)
  cy.wait("@statementUpdatedMap")  // wait for another call
})

Now the test passes when an individual line in the test has failed,

If a second call does occur, the test will fail.
Using the done() function prevents a false positive outcome.


The cy.get('@statementUpdatedMap.all') is currently valid syntax, although as mentioned not officially documented. It's been around a while so there's a good chance it will continue to be available.
This issue with it is you can only run it after you are sure all the calls have a response (cy.intercept() records on the response phase of a call).
So you could add a wait before calling it, but there are the usual caveats about that:
cy.wait(2000)
cy.get('@statementUpdatedMap.all')  ...

In this particular example, the cy.intercepts() are all stubbing so adding a wait is probably ok - there's no direct network involvement to break the test.
Having said that, running on CI can still cause a failure because the cloud servers are multi-tasking several virtual instances and can take several seconds to task-switch, so it's probably not a good idea in that environment.
There is another approach using https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-network-idle that looks useful, but it still requires a wait time to be specified.
There is a feature Pending calls that looks like it is watching requests rather than responses, which is what you really want to do. (The link on the ReadMe page is broken so I've linked directly to the test).
  cy.waitForNetworkIdle('@all', 2000, { timeout: 6000 })
    .should('have.keys', 'started', 'finished', 'waited', 'callCount')
    .then(({ waited, callCount }) => {
      // the page makes the Ajax call that resolves after 3 seconds
      // with 2 seconds of checking for network idle makes 5 seconds
      expect(waited, 'waited ms').to.be.within(5000, 6500)
      // the document and the Ajax
      expect(callCount, 'callCount').to.equal(2)
    })

If you want to use this idea without using the plugin, this is how I would do it in basic Cypress code
let calls = 0;
cy.intercept("POST", mapsPath, (req) => {

  // record the call upon request (should happen very soon after the 2nd click
  calls++;

  // reply with fixture as per original code
  req.reply({
    fixture: 'initDefaultMap.json'
  })
}).as("saveMap");

...  // initial code to set up the click

cy.wait("@saveMap");   // wait for the first call

...  // repeat code to click again

cy.get(something-that-appears-on-the-page-after-clicking) 
  .should('be.visible')                            // preferred way to wait
  .then(() => {
    expect(calls).to.eq(1)
  })


The cy.verifyFailed() command looks pretty solid, and can be used for more than just verifying intercept call.

cy.intercept() calls that are aliased (via cy.as()) can be queried via cy.get(). We can combine this with a (poorly documented) @alias.all request to get the entire list of times the alias was used (in this case, the number of times the intercept was triggered) and use the length of that result to validate that the call has only been made once.
Assuming the statementUpdatedMap alias is the call you want to validate has only been called once...
  it("update statement from the map is edited and sent only once", () => {
    cy.intercept("POST", mapsPath, { fixture: "initDefaultMap.json" }).as("saveMap");
    cy.intercept("POST", lrsPath, { fixture: "statementOpened.json" }).as("statementUpdatedMap");

    cy.get('[data-cy="canvas"]').click();
    cy.get("zt-color-picker[icon='bg-color']").shadow().find("zt-button").shadow().find(".zt-button").click();
    cy.get("zt-color-picker[icon='bg-color']")
      .shadow()
      .find("#color-picker-submenu > ul > li.color-boxes[data-color='#99FFCC']")
      .click();

    cy.wait("@statementUpdatedMap").then((evt) => expect(extractVerb(evt)).to.be.equal("updated"));
    cy.wait("@saveMap");
    cy.get('[data-cy="edit-title"]').click();
    cy.get("body [data-cy='input-title'] input").clear().type("mappa bella");
    cy.get('[data-cy="canvas"]').click();
    cy.get('@statementUpdatedMap.all').should('have.length', 1); // validating length of yielded calls is one
    cy.get("zt-color-picker[icon='bg-color']").shadow().find("zt-button").shadow().find(".zt-button").click();
    cy.get("zt-color-picker[icon='bg-color']")
      .shadow()
      .find("#color-picker-submenu > ul > li.color-boxes[data-color='#5533FF']")
      .click();
    cy.get('@statementUpdatedMap.all').should('have.length', 1); // validating length of yielded calls is one  });


You would need a 2nd cy.wait('@statementUpdatedMap') to correctly test, since cy.get('@statementUpdatedMap.all') does not wait and may occur too soon, giving a false positive result.

It's not actually documented at all - for the reason above, it shouldn't be used.

If there's only ever one call, having a second cy.wait('@statementUpdatedMap') would fail - that call is never made.

It's not documented, but the issue I linked was opened by a Cypress employee. There is a conversation in that thread about whether they should support it, but at the moment, they do, and I don't see a good reason to use it if it solves the problem.

The reason (as explained) is cy.get(alias.all) does not wait. So the 2nd call might occur after that line in the test, and your test will not catch it. Surely that is fairly clear, no?

Waiting for the call - which is not expected to come - would result in a test failure. Using an explicit wait (cy.wait(300)) is an anti-pattern https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait#Wait-for-an-arbitrary-period-of-milliseconds. You could move the cy.get('@alias.all') to the end of the test to validate after all actions have occurred, but ideally, the request is coming after a specific action and the cy.get can be called after the action.
